# How to achieve Nested fields structure in firestore document?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I wanted to achieve this structure. In my case, the subject field name will be a variable.

If you guys have any other suggestions please share it with me.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Try to be specific in asking your question. There must be other details that you can add, so edit the question if that is the case.

Comment: Guys please help me with this.

Comment: What do you mean through "I wanted to achieve this structure. In my case, the subject field name will be a variable."? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I mean to say that here subject will be provided by the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the desired structured you have to use `map` type fields. Use the following screenshot as a guide:

[image]

Please bear Firebase documentation for [Data Model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) in mind and also the [advantages and disadvantages](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/concepts/structure-data#nested_data_in_documents) of using this type of structure.

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: how can I put values programmatically?

Comment: This is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) on how to add data to Cloud Firestore.